# Angular dart child component scope

Tags: scope, dart, components, angular-dart

How to limit component events to it's parent/child components and prevent bubbling up.

I have the following two components:

**ParentComponent.dart**

```dart
@Component(
  selector: "parent-component",
  template: '<div>parent value: {{value}}<content></content></div>',
  useShadowDom: false
)
class ParentComponent implements ScopeAware{
  Scope _scope;

  @NgAttr('value')
  String value;

  void set scope(Scope scope){
    _scope = scope;
    _scope.on('select-child').listen((ScopeEvent event){
      value = event.data['value'];
    });
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent.dart**

```dart
@Component(
  selector: "child-component",
  template: '<div ng-click="select()">child: {{value}}</div>',
  useShadowDom: false
)
class ChildComponent implements ScopeAware{
  Scope _scope;

  @NgAttr('value')
  String value;

  void select(){
    _scope.parentScope.broadcast('select-child', {
      'value': value
    });
  }

  void set scope(Scope scope){
    _scope = scope;
  }
}
```

When one clicks on the child component, the parent updates its value.

But when i have more parent components they listen all to the same childs:

```dart
<!-- Parent 1 -->
<parent-component>
  <child-component value="foo"></child-component>
  <child-component value="bar"></child-component>
</parent-component>

<!-- Parent 2 -->
<parent-component>
  <child-component value="herp"></child-component>
  <child-component value="derp"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

When i click the foo child-component of parent1 both parent components change their value to 'foo'.

I already tried playing with emit, broadcast. I know broadcast bubbles downwards to the leaf nodes and emit bubbles up. I also tried usind "scope.createChild()" but i think i miss something.

How can i create a scope in parent which is only visible to the child and vice versa?
Or how to use broadcast emit correctly?

When i understand the docs right i have to use emit() in child-component and not parentNode.broadcast() but i can't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Your confusion is coming from the fact that while components do create new scopes, those scopes are only available to the shadowDom (the html in the template: annotation).

In your example all 6 components - 2 parents and 4 children, create scopes that are child scopes of root scope. So when you are calling parentScope.broadcast you are firing event from rootScope down to all 6 scopes.

The easiest way to achieve the behavior you want is to directly inject ParentComponent into ChildComponent. Parent components are injectable to components in both their light and shadow DOMs.

```
class ChildComponent implements ScopeAware {
  ParentComponent _p;    
  ChildComponent(this._p);
  void select(){
    _p.setValue(value);
  }
  ...
}
```

Only downside is that makes the two components more tightly coupled to each other, which is ok if you are authoring both for your own application.

Comment: In angulardart-1.0 ChildComponent(this._p); gives me the following error: 'package:angular/core_dom/view_factory.dart': Failed assertion: line 53 pos 12: 'scope != null' is not true.